# About Java GC and my stack implementation link list

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, stack, singly-linked-list

I decided to start studying Java a day ago. I choose to implement a stack (linked list implementation), and other data structure to learn it but I'm not quite sure about my code, and the behavior of Java's GC, can you guys check if my code is right or wrong?

I'm sorry I don't know any Java expert to ask if I'm doing things right.

BTW I came from C and C++ and I'm quite OC to the memory that my program occupies.

I tried to run this program and pushed 500mb of memory, then when I used the .pop() method the memory does not go down, I also waited for like 20mins and nothing happened.
What I have read is that java automatically deallocate memory for us, but since I don't see it goes down it feels like I'm doing this wrong.

**MY STACK**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// ------------------------  node  ------------------------
class node<type>{
    type value;
    node<type> prev;

    node(type value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    // for checking I guess
    void recdisp(node<type> recurs){
        if(recurs != null){
            System.out.println(recurs.value);
            recurs.recdisp(recurs.prev);
        }
        return;
    }
}

// ------------------------  STACK  ------------------------
class mystack<type>{
    node<type> top;

    mystack(type value){
        top = new node<type>(value);
        top.prev = null;
    }

    void push(type value){
        node<type> buffer = new node<type>(value);
        buffer.prev = top;
        top = buffer;
        buffer = null;
    }

    type pop(){
        node<type> tmp;
        if(top == null){
            System.out.println("POP: Stack is Empty");
            return null;
        }
        type pass = top.value;
        tmp = top;
        top = top.prev;
        tmp = null;
        return pass;
    }

    void peek(){
        System.out.println("TOP VALUE : "+top.value);
    }

    void display(){
        if(top != null)
            top.recdisp(top);
        else
            System.out.println("Display: Stack is empty");
    }
}


//  ------------------------  MAIN CLASS  ------------------------
public class myjava{
    public static void main(String []args){

        mystack<Integer> stacks = new mystack<Integer>(5);
        stacks.pop();
        stacks.pop();
        stacks.pop();
        stacks.display();

        stacks.push(10);
        stacks.push(20);
        stacks.push(30);
        stacks.push(40);

        stacks.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you expecting the memory to "go down"? The JVM ordinarily does not return allocated RAM to the OS, since it guesses that if it needed 500MB once, it will need it again.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic oh I see, I was looking at my system's memory, I thought that I can see it go down, but how can I look at this said memory usage of my program in the java virtual machine?, also is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

okay so, I already know now how to monitor the memory of my java program properly, I used the "jconsole" app to monitor the allocated heap memory in the JVM, but it seems that I need to click this "request garbage collection" before it can free up the .poped() memory out of my stack, I'm finding now a way to do this "request garbage collection" in my java program.

Comment: You don't need to 'request garbage collection' at all, the JVM by itself will decide when it is necessary to garbage collect (for example when it needs to allocate, but there is insufficient space). When it does depends on the Java version, selected garbage collector and its configuration.

Comment: As Mark said, it's fine to do this for purposes of learning about memory consumption, but it is neither necessary nor recommended in real applications; the JVM understands when to perform garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are several concepts involved here.

The JVM provides automatic memory management for your application.  Unlike C, you do not need to explicitly allocate space for an object; the JVM will do that for you in the heap.  When you no longer have any references to an object, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.  It is important to realise that when (or even if) the object will be collected is not guaranteed.

Most GC algorithms use a generational heap space (dividing it into young and old generations).  Almost all objects you create are only referenced for a very short time.  Most objects are collected in the young generation, reducing the load on the old generation.

Until fairly recently, the JVM was reluctant to return unused heap memory to the operating system.  In JDK 12, JEP 346 introduced prompt memory release for the G1 collector.  Some other collectors do similar things but not all.

From your question, it is not possible to say exactly what is happening.  You don't state how big your heap is (or how much memory your machine has).  Creating 500Mb of data may not even trigger a minor GC cycle if the young generation is big enough.  Also, much will depend on which version of the JDK you are using.